# Why assigning to globalenv not allowed when creating R package?

Tags: r, package, assign

I'm creating a R package and I have a function that returns an object which its name is constructed with the argument passed. 
I use the function `assign()` to do this as in the code below and it works fine.

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 2:11, C = 5:14)

ot_test <- function(df, min){
  tmp <- colSums(df)
  tmp2 <- df[, tmp >= min]
  assign(paste0(deparse(substitute(df)), "_min_", min), tmp2, envir= .GlobalEnv)
}
ot_test(df,60)
ls()
[1] "df"        "df_min_60" "ot_test"
```

But when I check the package with `devtools::check` I have the message.

```
Found the following assignments to the global environment:
File 'test/R/ottest.R':
assign(paste0(deparse(substitute(df)), "_min_", min), tmp2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Is there a way to do the same without having .GlobalEnv in argument or without using the function `assign()`.

Answer (score 3):

Its just an ugly, bad thing to do in a functional programming environment.

What's wrong with:

```
 df_min_60 = ot_test(df,60)
```

Your argument will be that your method saves a bit of typing, but it opens you up to all sorts of bugs and obscurities.

Suppose I want to call `ot_test` in a function, in a loop maybe. Now its stomped on, with no warning or obvious clue its going to do it, the `df_min_60` in my global workspace. Gee thanks for that. So what do I have to do?

```
ot_test(df, 60)
# now rename so I don't stomp on it
df_min_60.1 = df_min_60
results = domyloop(d1,d2,d3)
```

Which has meant **more** typing.

Now another idea. Suppose I want to call `ot_test` on a list of data frames and make a list of the results. Normally I'd do something like:

```
for(i in 1:10){res[[i]] = ot_test(data[[i]], 60)}
```

but with your code I can't. I have to do:

```
for(i in 1:10){d=data[[i]]; ot_test(d,60); res[[i]] = d_min_60)}
```

which is WAY more typing.

Be thankful that `devtools::check` only gives a message and doesn't set your computer on fire for doing this. Seriously, don't create things in the global environment, return them as return values.

Comment: Ok, I got the message. Don't use assign() function. It was pratical because in fact I applyed several functions sequently (like filters) on a datafame and it was a way to keep trace of each transformation.